# What is the size of pig charaarray

Tags: hive, apache-pig

I have string column in Hive which is contains mails(as a passage).I would like to process those column for text mining.Its not taking data taking as nulls.Is there any limitations in pig chararray.and please suggest me for this task. Thank you

Comment: If you have a hive string, it should be possible to process this as a pig chararray. Is this what you needed to know? (Your question is a bit unclear)

Comment: which modules are better to use for this task, sparksql, pig or any udfs required.

Comment: hive string column consist of mails data of users.i would like to mine this mails column.Thank you

Comment: When i'm searching text in that it's not giving any result. I got the warning as :-  WARN mapReduceLayer.PigHadoopLogger: org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter(FIELD_DISCARDED_TYPE_CONVERSION_FAILED): Unable to interpret value [0] in field being converted to double, caught NumberFormatException <empty String> field discarded

Comment: @RameshMuthavarapu hi ramesh .. i think you are using hcatalog for this . try using data type conversion from hive to hcatalog and then hcatalog to hive.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to use a chararray, but that the data is actually forced into a double. This could happen explicitly or implicitly (for instance when you try to use a number function like MAX on it).

Try to reduce your code to a minimum, then do a dump after each step and debug the following steps untill you achieve success:

1. Load the data, make sure the right datatype is used (check whether it still is a chararray (if it is already cast as a double, it should not show any text))
2. Do a describe, if your column is not yet chararray cast it to a chararray (and check the result)
3. Do your string operations (and check the result)
4. Write to your output